# Is it possible to run a spring webmvc webapp with spring security in one spring container?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here's my scenario: I've got a spring webapp (uses webmvc) that I just added spring security to.  I've got a CRUD user manager page that allows a user with sufficient privileges to add users.  On the server, this is handled by a com.myapp.UserController class.  I've also got my own implementation of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService, called com.myapp.UserDetailsServiceImpl.  Both the UserController and my UserDetailsService impl use a com.myapp.UserService that keeps track of users in a java.util.List.

What I found was that when I created a new user via my web interface, logged out, and then tried to log back in with that new user, the user is not found.  Upon closer inspection, it's because there are two different instances of com.myapp.UserService.  The one used by the UserController has the new user, but the one used by UserDetailsServiceImpl does not.

I tracked the cause down to the fact that two different spring containers run when I start this webapp.  One is for webmvc (myapp-servlet.xml), and one is for security (myapp-security.xml).  Each has its own instance of UserService.  It's my understanding that this is a pretty common scenario for configuring spring webmvc with security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/myapp-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In my myapp-servlet.xml, I've got component scanning going on, which picks up the UserService since it's annotated with @Service:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
```

But UserService is also picked up by myapp-security.xml, because it's referenced as part of my authentication-manager configuration:

```
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

Here is the relevant part of com.myapp.UserDetailsServiceImpl for completeness:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testUserService")
    private UserService userService;

    ...
}
```

And my UserController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testUserService")
    private UserService userService;

    ...
}
```

My question is this: is there a way to combine both the webmvc and the security into one spring container, so that I don't have duplicate instances of UserService being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Remove the */WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml* from the contextConfigLocation context param.

**Long Answer**

The *ContextLoaderListener* creates a root application context based on the configuration files defined in the contextConfigLocation and loads it into the ServletContext before any Servlet is initialized.

The DispatcherServlet at the same time, will create a child application context with the specified configuration. You are not explicitly specifying any bean definition file, so by convention it will take /WEB-INF/appName-servlet.xml (/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml in your case, which by chance exists). It happens that both your root application context and your child application context will have some common beans (duplicates, because they load the same configuration file).

You have two options:

1) Remove the /WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml from the contextConfigLocation. Additionally, if you want to be more explicit, add the configuration to the ServletDispatcher declaration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/myapp-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Note: the beans configured in myapp-servlet.xml will only be visible by the child application context, in case you want to access them from the root application context use the option 2 or reorganize your configuration files.

2) Load all the beans in the root application context (your current configuration), and add en empty configuration parameter in the dispatcher servlet.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergi, your answer worked.  I set the contextConfigLocation in the servlet config to empty, and added both the myapp-servlet.xml and myapp-security.xml to the global contextConfigLocation.

Answer (score 0):

Sergi's answer is correct.  For completeness, here's my working web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/myapp-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```